# Angularjs and jQuery $.noConflict()

Tags: javascript, dom, angularjs, jquery

Having some issues implementing any of the methods for noConflict. 
I'm not sure what is going on, the jQuery CDN loads before the Angularjs CDN also the file in which I try to use Jquery loads before any Angularjs files (controllers etc).

No jQuery functions are working when trying to implement this.

Anyone know what is going on?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/JS.js"></script>
<script src="../public/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/javascript/comsumer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/javascript/controllers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/javascript/services.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/javascript/directives.js"></script>
```

That is the order in which the files are called.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Code that isn't working - all noConflict

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
 // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Also

```
jQuery.noConflict();
 jQuery(".test").hide();
```

Also

```
jQuery.noConflict();
 (function($) {
   $(function() {
     // more code using $ as alias to jQuery
      $(".test").hide();
   });
})(jQuery);
  // other code using $ as an alias to the other library
```

Also

```
 var j = jQuery.noConflict();
   j(".test").hide();
```

lastly

```
var dom = {};
dom.query = jQuery.noConflict(true);
   dom.query(".test").hide();
```

none seem to work, I have put them in my JS file, none jQuery function are triggering

Comment: What error are you getting? What have you tried?  You haven't shown any code.

Comment: I mentioned I have used all the methods related to the noConflict jquery method, I am getting no errors, but jQuery methods are not working

Comment: @nullVoid - you aren't going to get help unless you show us the noConflict code you are using and show us a jQuery piece of code that doesn't work after it.  As it is, we have no idea what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I haven't gone through this in detail - but as you're wrapping your code in document.ready etc, it would be run when *everything* is loaded. Angular includes an internal version of jqlite - I suspect this is causing conflicts if you're using jquery.noConflict, perhaps overwriting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was staring me right in the face.
Issues being that angularjs SPA 'injected' the view that had the DOM element I wanted to use jQuery on, so still using .noConflict(), I had to use something like this.

The Global

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var j = $.noConflict();
</script>
```

this in JS file

```
j(document).off("click",".jtest",testclick ).on("click", ".jtest",testclick);
```

Jquery only sees the current DOM when loaded, so with it being injected using the above solution worked.

The detail of the question should have been better, my bad.